# GAE : Open Source Django Apps

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Am looking for open source Django apps in Google App engine. I want to play around with the code and learn in the process.

Not mandatory, but Would be great feature in the app:
- account registration/login
- image/file upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.uptosomething.in/weblog/?page_id=355) has some pointers to open source stuff running on GAE.  One of them is [Niubi](http://code.google.com/p/niubi/), which looks like a useful start.

Comment: niubi looks like what pinax is for non-gae :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to learn Django why don't you start with their tutorial? It's a great learning tool and takes roughly an hour to go through.
[Django Tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)